# wait for 2 parallel threads to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing image conversion on a thread and a progressbar display on a second one (parallely).

My problem is to detect that all the threads has been finished so I can get the Compressed File and save it using the `save` method.

With my actual code, the `save` method is being executed before the threads are terminated, so how can I achieve that ?

**My actual code :**

```
class Compression extends FileProcess {

    private Thread compressionThread;
    private Thread progressionThread;

    @Override
    protected void onStart () {
        // init data
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEnd () {

        // Wait here until all the threads are finished the 
        InputStream is = getFileContent (
                                new FileInputStream (
                                    new File ((String)params.get (FilePath))
                                );

        save (is); 
        System.out.println ("Done");
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getFileContent (InputStream input) {

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream ("aa.jpg");

        compress (input, os);

    }

    @Override
    protected void compress (InputStream input, OutputStream output) {

        compressionThread = new Thread () {

            @Override
            public void run () {

                // Compression process

            }
        };
        compressionThread.start ();

        progressionThread= new Thread () {

            @Override
            public void run () {

                // Progression windows

            }
        };
        progressionThread.start ();

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `join` your threads.

Comment: put the following at the end of compress() :
compressionThread.join();
progressionThread.join();

Comment: Thank you ! But apparently the Threads are no longer being executed Simultaneously like I wanted. They are executed successively.

Comment: No, that is not possible with just `join` (assuming you put them after **both** `start()` calls).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : you mean that to keep the parallelism I have to put both `join` after `progressionThread.start ();` right ?

Comment: Yes, start both thread, **then** join them.